# save(Object)" because "this.userRepo" is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**When I post the data that time getting this error**

Cannot invoke "com.helpmydesk.Repo.UserRepo.save(Object)" because "this.userRepo" is null
at com.helpmydesk.InterFaceAndService.ServiceClass.execute(ServiceClass.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
at com.helpmydesk.ControllerClass.execute(ControllerClass.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]

**Main Class**

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("package com.helpmydesk.Repo.UserRepo")
@SpringBootApplication
public class HelpmydeskApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelpmydeskApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Controller Class**

```
@Controller
public class ControllerClass {

     @Autowired 
    private InterfaceClass interfaceClass;
 
    public ControllerClass(InterfaceClass interfaceClass) {
        this.interfaceClass = interfaceClass;

    }

    @PostMapping("/doregister")
    public User execute(@RequestBody User user) {

        return this.interfaceClass.execute(user);

    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "home";

    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/singup")
    public String singup() {
        return "singup";
}
}
```

**Repository Class**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

**interface Class**

```
public interface InterfaceClass {
    public User execute(User user);
}
```

**Service Class**

```
@Service
public class ServiceClass implements InterfaceClass {
    
    private UserRepo userRepo;
    
    public User execute(User user) {
        this.userRepo.save(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

**User Class**

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {
    
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String role;
    private boolean enabled;
    private String imageUrl;
    @Column(length = 500)
    private String about;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private java.util.List<Blog> blogs = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public User() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }
    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
    public String getAbout() {
        return about;
    }
    public void setAbout(String about) {
        this.about = about;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email + ", password=" + password + ", role=" + role
                + ", enabled=" + enabled + ", imageUrl=" + imageUrl + ", about=" + about + "]";
    }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZ8nT.png)

Comment: Evidently `userRepo` is null. You never set it to anything. Did you mean to autowire it?

Comment: Based on your code you are missing an injection of your `private UserRepo userRepo;` Annotate the field with `@Autowired;` or use a constructor which accepts an instance of  `UserRepo` which then will be injected on bean creation. Either way an instance is injected. Otherwise it will be null.

Comment: When I use @Autowired on private UserRepo userRepo; getting below error  (Field userRepo in com.helpmydesk.InterFaceAndService.ServiceClass required a bean of type 'com.helpmydesk.Repo.UserRepo' that could not be found.
)

Comment: Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.helpmydesk.Repo.UserRepo' in your configuration.

Comment: `@EnableJpaRepositories("package com.helpmydesk.Repo.UserRepo")` this looks somehow wrong to me. Should it not be `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.helpmydesk.Repo")` or just `@EnableJpaRepositories`

Comment: When i use only @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.helpmydesk.Repo") or this @EnableJpaRepositories give me lots of error.@Daniel Wosch

Comment: Error(Error creating bean with name 'controllerClass' defined in file [C:\react js\helpmydesk\target\classes\com\helpmydesk\ControllerClass.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceClass' defined in file [C:\react js\helpmydesk\target\classes\com\helpmydesk\InterFaceAndService\ServiceClass.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;

Comment: pls give me the solution of this issue @ Daniel Wosch

Answer (score 2):

You don't have `@Autowired` on your `UserRepo` variable. You can add it; the better fix is to eliminate field injection and use an ordinary constructor. Spring will provide all of the necessary dependencies when it calls the constructor, it makes testing much easier, and it prevents problems of this sort.

Comment: If u possible to explain how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: @user15038721 I wrote you a specific explanation.

Comment: private UserRepo userRepo;
 
 
 
 public ServiceClass(UserRepo userRepo) {
  this.userRepo=userRepo;
 } i had tried but still getting same error

Comment: pls help me pls

Answer (score 0):

you should add @Autowired in your service class before ligne UserRepo userRepo
because userRepo must be injected before using it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).